# How to change Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.FormRecognizer v0.8.0-preview API endpoint to v.2.0.0?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm currently training a custom model (manual labeling) using [the OCR labeling tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool) 
I noticed the model was stored on the **https:///formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models** endpoint.

The Form Recognizer .NET SDK (Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.FormRecognizer v0.8.0-preview) are currently directed to the v1.0.0-endpoint because the model id is not available when I executed a GET request to **https:///formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models** and It did exists on **https:///formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models**. Does anybody know how to fix this problem without having to implement the REST API manually all over again or waiting for the next version of nuget package to come out?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this website for the code snippets of how to use the v2.0 REST API: 
aka.ms/Form-aka.ms/Form-Recognizer/api 
The current SDK only supports v1.0 release, but the SDK for v2.0 release is coming soon. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Azure SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/2020-04/dotnet.html) [Azure.AI.FormRecognizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/1.0.0-preview.1) preview library supporting Form Recognizer service version 2.0-preview is now available.  Details on how to use it can be found in the [package README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/b3347bcc48845e36500a6986fb48f1e31e68b0cb/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/README.md).